# Hide summary if empty (no trimming)

Tags: 7, views, entities

In many cases we're using a view of content using the *summary or trimmed text* of a body field. Clients sometimes remark that, if there's nothing in the summary, nothing should be displayed at all, so no trimmed text of the full content either (which Views does by default).

Instinctively I went looking in the *Behaviour when no results* options of that body field in the View, but couldn't find anything there that would hide the summary if the summary is empty, disregarding what's in the full content.

What would be the recommended approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check the *Rewrite the value of this field*-option of the body field,
2. Fill out the following token in the text area: `[body-summary]`

Now it will only display text from the summary, and nothing when that very summary is empty. So it won't use the trimmed text of the full content either. Perfect.

Comment: You are awesome!